# Access violation when calling glfwSwapBuffers only on NVIDIA cards with LWJGL3

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

Sorry to bother you but I couldn't fix it by myself.
I think the problem is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373952/glfwswapbuffers-causing-access-violation-only-when-rendering-geometry-using-gld) but unfortunately there was no valid answer.
My program works perfectly fine when using an Intel graphic card, but when I use an nvidia graphic card (an rtx 3080) it crashes when calling glfwSwapBuffers. I did some debugging and I found out that the fault is of the water renderer glDrawElements call.
What is even weirder is that the program doesn't instantly crash but it can successfully render some tiles of water (the terrain is rendered without any issue).
That issue appeared when I started using two opengl context, one for loading vertices in the vbos and one for rendering. What I can't understand it's why it only works on non-nvidia's graphic cards.

```
override fun render() {
        moveFactor += waveSpeed * interval
        shaderProgram.bind()
        shaderProgram.setUniform("reflectionTexture", 0)
        shaderProgram.setUniform("refractionTexture", 1)
        shaderProgram.setUniform("dudvMap",2)
        shaderProgram.setUniform("normalMap",3)
        shaderProgram.setUniform("moveFactor",moveFactor)
        shaderProgram.setUniform("projectionMatrix", GameEngine.projectionMatrix)
        shaderProgram.setUniform("cameraPosition", camera.position)
        entities.forEach { entry ->
            val mesh = entry.key
            initRender(mesh)
            entry.value.forEach { gameItem ->
                val modelViewMatrix = gameItem.transformation.getModelViewMatrix(camera.viewMatrix)
                shaderProgram.setUniform("modelViewMatrix", modelViewMatrix)
                shaderProgram.setUniform("modelMatrix", gameItem.transformation.getModelMatrix())

//-------------> HERE IS WHERE THE PROGRAM CRASH. If I comment that line the glfwSwapBuffer call works fine
                GL13C.glDrawElements(GL13C.GL_TRIANGLES, mesh.vertices.size, GL13C.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)

            }
            endRender()
        }
        shaderProgram.unbind()
    }

    private fun initRender(mesh: Mesh) {
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
        GL30C.glBindVertexArray(mesh.vao.id)
        GL13C.glActiveTexture(GL13C.GL_TEXTURE0)
        GL13C.glBindTexture(GL13C.GL_TEXTURE_2D, waterFrameBuffers.reflectionTexture)
        GL13C.glActiveTexture(GL13C.GL_TEXTURE1)
        GL13C.glBindTexture(GL13C.GL_TEXTURE_2D, waterFrameBuffers.refractionTexture)
        GL13C.glActiveTexture(GL13C.GL_TEXTURE2)
        GL13C.glBindTexture(GL13C.GL_TEXTURE_2D, dudvTexture.id)
        GL13C.glActiveTexture(GL13C.GL_TEXTURE3)
        GL13C.glBindTexture(GL13C.GL_TEXTURE_2D, normalMap.id)
        GL11C.glEnable(GL30C.GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0)
    }

    private fun endRender() {
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
        GL11C.glDisable(GL30C.GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0)
    }
```

Do NVIDIA's graphic cards need some particular opengl function to be called before and after rendering?
I'm using LWJGL3 but I don't think it's a binding problem, that's why I also added the opengl tag (I could be wrong so I apologize if I used the opengl tag inappropriately).

Comment: Since you talk about multiple contexts, I assume you are using multiple threads: Are they synchronized correctly? Especially the write access to the arrays which are used by glDrawElements? Where exactly (and on which thread) does the call to glfwSwapBuffers happen?

Comment: Yes they are correctly synchronized. The glfwSwapBuffers is  called in the first context, which also calls the glDrawElements. The second context calls the glBufferData methods and then store a mesh object in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue; the first context at every update cycle poll a mesh, buffers its indices and then marks it as ready to be rendered. I know it's a bit tricky but VAOs are not shared between contexts so I had to finalize the buffering of the mesh in the first context. Never had a concurrent modification exception, nor a vao/vbo used by two or more meshes,nor a  null vao/vbo pointer

Comment: I don't think it's a synchronization problem because on my laptop works perfectly fine. It just crashes on my pc with an nvidia's graphic card (rtx 3080 with latest drivers)

Comment: "The second context calls the glBufferData methods and then store a mesh object in a ConcurrentLinkedQueue; the first context at every update cycle poll a mesh, buffers its indices and then marks it as ready to be rendered." But that is not correct. After the `glBufferData` call has finished in the second thread, there is no guarantee  that the GL has finished updating the buffer (all what is guaranteed at this point is that the GL has consumed your user-space buffer data, so you can chagne that afterwards). You need to use GL synchronization primitives to make this work.

Comment: "I don't think it's a synchronization problem because on my laptop works perfectly fine." It is the nature of race conditions that they are extremely sensitive to timing and external factors of all sorts.

Comment: You mean that I might be drawing a vao whose vbos are empty or being filled by the second context? This might explain why on intel gpu works and on nvidia not. So if I put a glFinish() after the glBufferData I will fix it right? Because then when  I add the mesh to the queue I will be sure that all the vertices have been buffered in the vbos

Comment: I added glFinish() and it seemed to have fixed the issue but after 30 seconds the program crashed again. I think that there might be another synchronization problem somewhere else. But now I'm definetely a thousand steps closer to fix it. EDIT: I found it. Thank you so much! I completely forgot that OpenGL calls are asynchronous. If you want to write the answer I will mark it as a correct solution